# jboss - class not found in module call

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x

I have apache commons lang in my ear, and I am calling an ejb, which has all the jars in ear folder and properly configured, yet when I call the ear I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:    
org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder from [Module "test.common:main"
```

which is thrown from a module I created(compile) that uses commons lang. Why doesn't jboss use commons lang from the ear deployment? is there somewhere else I should but the jar's outside of the ear so the module can use them?

Answer (score 1):

The EAR is isolated, so your module can't see what you have packaged in your EAR.

The module itself is isolated as well. So you will need to provide dependencies for "commons lang" to the module in the `module.xml` file of the module. For instance JBossAS7 provides a commons-lang module. You can include that as a dependency in the module.xml:

```
 <dependencies>
    <module name="org.apache.commons.lang" />
 </dependencies>
```

Similarly you can add the same dependency in your `EAR/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` . This way both module and EAR will use the same commons-lang jar so you can avoid CLassCastExceptions.

Alternatively, you can add `export="true"` for the dependency in the `module.xml` so that when you include your module it exports its dependencies to other packages.